# Cannot extract the string value of the Dictionary<hashable,String>

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have declared following dictionary

```
var locations:Dictionary<String,String> = ["loc1":"Los Angeles","loc2":"San Francisco"];
```

then trying to simply assign it to a `variable` rather than a `constant`

```
var location:String = locations["loc1"];
```

but then the compiler is complaining about : `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

If I change `var location:String = locations["loc1"];` to var `location:String? = locations["loc1"];` ,which means the String is optional, compiler error goes away.

but as you can see I haven't defined my dictionary to be optional e.g. `Dictionary<String,String?>`. So just wondering why does Swift convert my value type to be optional string(String?) behind the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that pulls the value of the dictionary does not know whether or not `locations["loc1"]` will return a value - it could also return `nil`. Thus, it cannot be assigned to a non-optional `String`, as that would be a guarantee that the String is not nil, which is not the case.

However, if you want `location` as a non-optional String, you can initialize it, then use `if let` to unwrap the value from the dictionary:

```
var location : String = "Unknown"
if let value = locations["loc1"] {
     location = value
}
```

Slightly more verbose, but guarantees that `location` contains either a value or `"Unknown"` and cannot be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your dictionary may not contain a value for that key so it returns a String optional just in case.